# CPU reaches 100 percent with starting of my python script which handles HTTP requests through socket programming?

Tags: python, sockets, http

I am writing a script for handling HTTP request through socket programming. My Python Script just reads each HTTP response, search for few keywords and increment the counters.

Only starting the script takes CPU upto 90-99% when there is no incoming messages. How should i handle this?

```html
HOST = '' 
SOCKET_LIST = []
RECV_BUFFER = 40966 
PORT=int(sys.argv[1])
serviceInitiatedEvent=0
deliveredEvent=0
EstablishedEvent=0
ConnectionClearedEvent=0

def chat_server():

    server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    server_socket.bind((HOST, PORT))
    server_socket.listen(10)
 
    SOCKET_LIST.append(server_socket)
 
    print "Chat server started on port " + str(PORT)
  
    try:
     while 1:
  
        ready_to_read,ready_to_write,in_error = select.select(SOCKET_LIST,[],[],0)
      
        for sock in ready_to_read:
            if sock == server_socket: 
                sockfd, addr = server_socket.accept()
                SOCKET_LIST.append(sockfd)
                 
            
            else:
                  try:
                    data = sock.recv(RECV_BUFFER)
                    if data:
         if re.search('serviceInitiatedEvent></SOAP-ENV',data):
     global serviceInitiatedEvent
     serviceInitiatedEvent+=1
         if re.search('deliveredEvent></SOAP-ENV',data):
     global deliveredEvent
     deliveredEvent+=1 

                    else:
 
                        if sock in SOCKET_LIST:
                            SOCKET_LIST.remove(sock)

                except:
                    broadcast(server_socket, sock, "Client (%s, %s) is offline\n" % addr)
                    continue
                    
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
                    print "service Initiated Event:%s" % (serviceInitiatedEvent)
                    print "delivered Event: %s" % (deliveredEvent)


    server_socket.close()
    

 
if __name__ == "__main__":

    sys.exit(chat_server())
```

Comment: This is because you run your server with a `while 1`, you should rather use a `handler` and `server.serve_forever` to handle more gracefully incoming connections (see [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html)). If needed I can write a small example

Comment: Thanks @Adonis - An example will be really appreciable...

Answer (score 2):

If you have code with `while 1` loop utilizing 100%, that's probably the culprit. It's called [busy waiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting).

[`select`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html#select.select) function has `timeout` parameter that specifies how long it should wait for events. In your code, you set it to `0`, so that when there is no data available in sockets, control returns immediately, causing busy waiting loop.

Specify some larger timeout, based on your needs, so that your code won't spin when there's nothing to do:

```
ready_to_read,ready_to_write,in_error = select.select(SOCKET_LIST,[],[], 1)
#                                                                       ^^^ here
```